# Is this random walk well studied?

Tags: probability, random, random-walk

Suppose that we have an ergodic finite Markov chain $C$ with a fintie state space $S$, and 
we have random variables $X_s$ where $s\in S$. Consider 
the following random walk

$S_0=0$ and $S_{i+1}=S_i +X_{C_i}$.

(In words, the random walk $S$ is somehow time-inhomogeneous.)

Is the property of this random walk well studied? Can I get some reference. Thanks.

Comment: 29271: Any luck with an answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model is called *random walk in random scenery*. It was introduced by Harry Kesten and Frank Spitzer in 1979 in their paper [A limit theorem related to a new class of self similar processes](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00535672) and is an active research subject: see the book *Random Walk in Random And Non-Random Environments* by Pál Révész, and the [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608219) by Frank den Hollander and Jeffrey E. Steif, somewhat more oriented towards the ergodic properties.

Answer (score 0):

Look for markov random walk or markov renewal process. It depends what you are interested in,  but that latter are discussed briefly in Ross' probability models.